# Getting the next hundred records from getAddressBook(JDE BSSV)

Tags: soap, wsdl, jdedwards, node-soap

I am making a request to `/AddressBookManager?WSDL` invoking `getAddressBook`, I am getting the first hundred records from it and the question would be if there's a way to get the next hundred then the next hundred(pagination)?

I've been looking for possible solutions like sending parameters/arguments to the method when invoking it just want to know if this is possible at all.

I don't have access to the JDE and was just given the wsdl, and having a hard time guessing what is possible or not.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

The code(node.js):

```
client.AddressBookManagerService.AddressBookManagerPort.getAddressBook({args could be inserted here to be passed}, function(err,response){
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see the schema if you look inside the WSDL file under the types tag under *`schemaLocation`*:

```
     <types>
      <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP550101/" schemaLocation="https://BlahBlah/AddressBookManager?xsd=1" />
      </xsd:schema>
    </types>
```

Inspecting that file, you should see XML elements - check those to see if there are elements that define the page number, records per page, sort index etc.

```
 <xs:complexType name="f0101Get">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="tns:valueObject">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="pageNumber" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="recordNumberPerPage" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="sortIndex" type="xs:int" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

If those exist, setting those values in your request should give you the functionality that you need.